# installing node.js via puppet; package not found

Tags: node.js, vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to install node.js on a Vagrant box using puppet. My Vagrantfile (Debian Wheezy) has the following configuration:

```
config.vm.provision :puppet, run: "always" do |puppet|
  puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
  puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
  puppet.options = '--verbose'
end
```

Inside `puppet/modules` I have the official `puppetlabs-nodejs` module (renamed to just `nodejs`). Inside `puppet/manifests` I'm starting out small - `default.pp` is just this:

```
Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }
include nodejs
```

When I run `vagrant provision` I get the following errors:

```
==> default: err: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Package[nodejs]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install nodejs' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: E: Unable to locate package nodejs
==> default: 
==> default: err: /Stage[main]/Nodejs/Package[npm]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install npm' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: E: Unable to locate package npm
==> default:
```

Far as I can tell I'm following [the readme](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/nodejs). Is that readme incomplete? Is there more to installing node than just including the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add run the following first to pull in the pointers to the packages.

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -`

You will need an `exec` block to do this.

exec block with that command, and creates set to '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list'

Comment: Had to use an `exec` block with that command, and `creates` set to `'/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list'`. I think it worked...there are some other errors that I don't think are related, but I'll continue to look into it.

Comment: You don't need to run that as an exec, you can use the `apt` type to include  it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an exec, you could use the `manage_package_repo` parameter:

```
  package { 'nodejs':
    ensure              => present,
    manage_package_repo => true,
  }
```

This will run this Puppet code (which is the same as the exec, but more idempotent!)

```
if ($ensure == 'present') {
    apt::source { 'nodesource':
      include_src       => $enable_src,
      key               => '1655A0AB68576280',
      key_source        => 'https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key',
      location          => 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node',
      pin               => $pin,
      release           => $::lsbdistcodename,
      repos             => 'main',
      required_packages => 'apt-transport-https ca-certificates',
    }
  }
```

Comment: First off, looks like the package uses `manage_repo` instead of `manage_package_repo`. However, even with that change, I get the following output: `==> default: Invalid parameter manage_repo at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/manifests/default.pp:25 on node a.b.c.d`.

Comment: Which version of the module are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.7.1, which should be the most recent stable build.

Comment: It looks like there's been a large refactor since then: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-nodejs/compare/0.7.1...master is it possible to use the version from master?

Comment: Possibly, though we generally stick to stable builds for customer projects.